# Is it possible to run python code using spark-sumit on cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I can able to run python code using spark-submit on local mode, is it possible to run python code on cluster mode ? anyone tried ?

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, it will be important to verify that your Python path settings are correct but it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Holden, but i read in below link about python on cluster mode, there they mentioned we cant use python on cluster mode, but heard from    a person statting that they were able run pyhon on cluster mode in Hortonworks, which i am not sure, and i am using IBMBiginsights . can you please give clear picture ? Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: The bellow link refers to yarn cluster mode versus yarn client mode, sorry I thought you were asking about running the cluster versus on the local machine instead of the two different Yarn deployment options.

Comment: @tkumaran What I usually think of as the "cluster mode" is called "standalone" in the Spark world (in opposition to a "ressource managed cluster" with Mesos or Yarn).